# Plugin for UPS Barcode for jqMobi

Tags: javascript, ios, html, jqmobi

I am need of a plugin for a web based app using appMobi with jqMobi as the framework.  I need to be able to read UPC codes while do a barcode scan.  I can get it work flawlessly with Android, but am not able to use my current code to work with IOS.  Does anyone know of a plugin for appMobi, jqMobi, or a way in java-script to get this work?

I have researched a great deal and have came across a few suggestions of implementing another barcode app from the App Store like pic2shop, but can not seem to get it work.  Just wondering if anyone has successively created a plugin for jqMobi would be great?  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score -1):

appMobi has an API for that, see:
http://www.appmobi.com/documentation/jsAPI/device/scanBarcode/index.html

Comment: I am aware of how to use the Barcode Scanning function, but in IOS it does now scan UPS Codes (1D codes).  It only will scan a QR Code.